# Open a link from Java, how to hide GET parameter

Tags: java, web

I want to open a link from Java I tried this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
         //Set your page url in this string. For eg, I m using URL for Google Search engine
         String url = "http://myurl.com?id=xx";
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));       
       }
       catch (java.io.IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
```

It is working fine but the problem is that the query string is in that url. I don't want to pass it as a query string because it is a secret key. It should be passed as hidden to webpage request. How can I do this?

Comment: not at all. you should now, that also when a webbrowser opens a url using a key that you can't see, it is simply not in the address field. it will be sent quite visible through the network.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, directly

You'd need to use a POST instead of a GET to *hide* the value and the URL does **not** encode the method used to access it, so it will always use GET.

You *could* conceivably write out a HTML file that automagically does a POST to the desired URL (using some JavaScript) and open that (using a `file://` URL).

But note that "hiding" the parameter like this adds *no real security*! An interested user that wants to know the value that his PC sends to some site **will be able to see it**. It might take *slightly* more effort to find it, but it's definitely not impossible.

Comment: @Nighil: no. If you understood what I was writing, that would not be your next question. And if you don't understand, then an example won't help.

Comment: if user copy the url then it will cause the problem that is why  i want to hide the query string. only thing i needed is user's can only browse this site by java only

Comment: You can't do that. Even hiding the URL as I describe won't help with that: he'll still be able to find the information you're transmitting.

Comment: here i am passing ipaddress of system as url key and checking in db if this ip is permitted to view this then only he can view this site, as far as normal users are concerned they will think that this will work only by this java application

Comment: @Nighil: that's a **terrible** security mechanism that's incredibly easy to subvert. Also: do you want that mechanism to prevent *average users* to "hack" your system, or do you want to avoid attackers with *some know-how*? Hint: it's the latter!

Answer (score 1):

If there is no need to show the particular url in a browser, then you could handle the link as an HttpURLConnection (see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)).

And [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139) you have an example.